# How does a single-track Turing machine simulate a multi-track Turing machine?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, simulation

It's easy to see how a multi-track Turing machine can simulate a single-track Turing machine; it does so by ignoring all but the first track. But how does it work the other way? I need a specification of a transition function that does the job. If there are $k$ tracks, then we can think of symbols as being vectors and arrange them one after another in the tape; but again, what's the transition function like in the equivalent single-track machine?

Comment: This is a fairly standard exercise. What are your specific problems with the transition function? (I seem to remember that there are some related questions around, discussion the performance impact of such a simulation.)

Comment: @Raphael If $\delta_k(q, [x_1,\dots,x_k]) = [y_1,\dots,y_k]$ where $\delta_k$ is the multi-track transition function, how is $\delta$, the single-track transition function, defined as to guarantee equivalence?

Comment: I think you need a more general idea before looking at individual transitions. You may need to do some additional bookkeeping/tape management not easily seen/expressed in single transitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\Sigma = (x_1,...,x_n)$ is the alphabet of the $m$-tracks $TM$, just use an expanded alphabet $\Sigma' = \Sigma \times ... \times \Sigma$ for the single-track $TM'$  ($|\Sigma'| = n^m$).

Every vector $\bar{x}_i$ of $m$ symbols from $\Sigma$ can be mapped to a unique alphabet symbol $u_i$ in $\Sigma'$: $\bar{x}_i = (x_{i_1},x_{i_2},...,x_{i_m}) \rightarrow u_i \in \Sigma'$

Hence every transition of $TM$ $(q_h,(x_{i_1},x_{i_2},...,x_{i_m}))\rightarrow (q_k,(x_{j_1},x_{j_2},...,x_{j_m}),dir)$
can be mapped to an equivalent transition in $TM'$ where the "read vector" $\bar{x_i}$ and "write vector" $\bar{x_j}$ are replaced with the corresponding alphabet symbols in $\Sigma'$: $(q_h,u_i)\rightarrow (q_k,u_j,dir)$

Comment: Clear, but one question. Do the symbols in $\Sigma'$ have length $=1$? That's bugging me.

Comment: @saadtaame, yes all the $u_{i}$s are single symbols, there's just $\Sigma^{m}$ of them.

Comment: @Vor I accepted this answer but now as I'm reading I have new questions. Why is there only one $dir$ in the transition function of the m-tracks TM? Isn't it that every track has a head that can move left, right, or not move at all?

Comment: @saadtaame: no, if the heads can move independently (in different directions), then the name of the model is [*multitape* Turing machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitape_Turing_machine), not [*multitrack* Turing machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-track_Turing_machine) as in your question (and in my answer :)

Comment: I imagine that the simulation is much harder then.

Comment: Not too much harder: you can simulate a $k$-tapes Turing machine with a one-tape Turing machine extending the alphabet like in the multi-track case (k-tapes are merged into a single tape) and adding $k$ extra symbols that are "placed" in the tape and are used to keep track of the heads positions. If you  want further details you can search with Google (there are many proofs available), read  M.Sipser's Introduction to the Theory of Computation (one of the best books) or ask another question here (but only after doing some self-study :-)